# Customize and override default magento meta tags in <head> for better SEO

Tags: magento2, seo, meta-tags

in my product pages, my meta description tag is taking the product description despite the configurations that I set in ***Store > Config > Catalog > Catalog***, where I set the description to `{{short_description}}`, but I always get the *long*-description content on the

`<meta name="description" content="...">`

Beyond that, there is the `<meta property="og:description" content="Short Description.">`, which always get the short description, I've tried to reidex, clean cache, delete static files, recompile, etc, but magento seems to ignore my configs. So I've searched to other ways to do that, overriding or something, and I find [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88558/product-description-is-used-as-meta-description), but this doesn't appear to be a magento 2 solution.

So, any ideas of how can I override the default magento 2 meta description tags?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will do some customization for that.
Using event Observer you change Product meta description as per your requirement i giving one observer event its usefull for that.

```
<event name="controller_action_postdispatch">
        <observer name="vendor_name_module_name_observer_meta" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SeoMetaObserver"/>
</event>
```

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory as BaseUrlRewrite;

class SeoMetaObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $urlRewriteFactory;
    protected $registry;
    protected $design;
    protected $context;
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        BaseUrlRewrite $rewriteFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $catalogOutput
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->request = $context->getRequest();
        $this->design = $context->getDesignPackage();
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->objManager= $objManager;
        $this->catalogOutput = $catalogOutput;
        $this->urlRewriteFactory = $rewriteFactory;
    }
    protected function getProductCollection()
    {
        $currentProduct = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        return $currentProduct;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $eventData = $observer->getData();
        if ($this->request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
            $currentProduct = $this->registry->registry('current_product')->getId();
            $title = $productname;
            $productdescription = $description;
            $productshortdescription = $shortdescription;
            $productfulldescription = $fulldescription;
            $layout = $this->context->getLayout();
            $pageMainTitle = $layout->getBlock('page.main.title');
            $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle("productname");
            $currentProduct->setDescription("product_description");
            $currentProduct->setShortDescription("short_description");
            $currentProduct->setFullDescription("full_descriptiom");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, it has given me a direction to do that, but actually I did it a bit different, I'll post my answer below, but really thanks

Comment: This is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I've followed the @Tushar answer, but make it a bit different, lets see how to do that:

I've created this event:

```
<event name="catalog_controller_product_view">
    <observer name="my_custom_metatags" instance="Vendor\Metatags\Observer\Product\CustomMetatags" />
</event>
```

With it, our Observer is only called on product view page, which is what I want.

And my Observer (I don't need to inject anything, so without constructor)

```
<?php
...

class CustomMetatags implements ObserverInterface {

public function execute(Observer $observer){
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    // trates meta-description
    if (!$product->getMetaDescription()) {
        $short = $product->getShortDescription();
        if (!$short) {
            $short = $product->getDescription();
        } else {
            $short = $product->getName().' - '.$short;
        }
        $product->setMetaDescription($short);
    }

    // trates ALT atribute in images
    $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        if(!$image->getLabel()) {
            $image->setLabel('Image '.$count.' - '.$product->getName());
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

And that's all! With this, my meta-description **first** attempt to get the proper field `meta_description`, if this is not filled in our product the **second** field to attempt is `short_description` and if it is not filled too, **finally** gets the `description` field content to set in meta-description tag.

The same with the images, if the `label` is not filled, then we add a custom label with product name and a counter.

I hope it helps someone in future, thanks to Tushar to show me the way.

Comment: It it is usefull solution please upvoted and right them.